# HTML page keeps refreshing indefinitely only in Firefox

Tags: html

A webpage in my web application work fine in all browsers except Firefox.
Firefox keeps refreshing the page indefinetly.
What can be the reason for this?

Sample page url : http://www.proders.com/temp/temp

Running it on chrome seems to be working fine.

Comment: Please add some code in your post. This can have a lot of reasons.

Comment: Have you tried using Firefox Safe Mode? Couple of things it could be based on the functionality in safe mode

Comment: @HobbsBear I did not use safe mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from your html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="; url=giris.xhtml" />
```

As I can see you are redirecting from this URL:

```
http://www.proders.com/temp/temp
```

to

```
 http://www.proders.com/temp/giris.xhtml
```

and again from **giris.xhtml** to **temp**, So technically it's in infinite loop.

Comment: Use this line and you may get same result in chrome also:
**<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=giris.xhtml" />**

Comment: Orijinal code : <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}; url=giris.xhtml"/>